# Adding Space Between Two Strings

Tags: xml, xslt

I am struck in a tricky situation. I am using Apache FOP to generate PDF files. First I am generating a Xml file by using Stringbuffer in Java class,next I am applying XSL template on the Xml file which is finally translated into pdf.

But the problem is for one  tag I have one  tag. so now I have a situation where in I will have multiple answer in one  tag.
So I am using String.append() to store all values in one string and finally displaying the same. but I want the values to come in different line rather than same line, but I am unable to do.

Please Help.

Thanks.

Comment: I am not very much familiar with JAVA. But if you have something like string join where you may add your string with some defined character let us say {{}} multiple braces, use it. And after that make a template in you xslt to trace out these braces and put it into mutiple <fo:block> element to display into multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

As you have full control over the XML you write out, why don't you write multiple XML elements ("tags") for the answers, one element for every answer (let's assume you use "answer" as an element name). Then you can use your XSLT to generate e.g. one "fo:block" element per "answer" element.

In case I misunderstood what you want to do, please make your question more specific by adding some example data.